# Custom device in Chrome devtools does not render correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

Surprisingly i just discovered that the "add custom device" in "Emulated devices" in Chrome devtools does not render my media queries as the actually appear on real devices. I just tested this on the Samsung S8 and the iPhone XS.

I added them with the correct viewport resolution, device pixel ratio (DPR) and "User agent string". From before I had already added my own mobile, the Huawei P20 Pro.

To my *big* surprise both the iPhone XS and the Samsung S8, as well as the already added P20 Pro device, rendered the site I'm currently working on just as expected (the media queries works as expected), while on *actual* devices only the P20 Pro looks like the devtools version - the S8 and the XS renders as if they respond to the "medium device" media query (max-width: 992px). I'm surprised because all three of the devices repsond to my queries as I'd expect in devtools (they all look more or less the same - as they should too), only the S8 and XS behave differently on actual devices.

First i thought maybe I should enter the actual resolution (not the viewport) in stead, but then all the native ones and my custom P20 works fine. The iPhone XS is listed with a viewport-/css-width of 375px, and the S8 with 360, so i just don't understand why the media queries don't work when they're set at max-width 415px and they work fine on the P20.

I obviously need to work on my media queries, but it's hard to do when I don't have the devices in my devtools to test the queries on.

Can anyone give me push in the right direction here?